# What is the THISMAKEFILE variable in make

Tags: makefile, build, msbuild, gnu-make

I am learning about MAKE files and going through some make files. I have come across several make files which defines a variable called THISMAKEFILE, which is set to the name of the makefile itself--

```
THISMAKEFILE = $(MAKEFILEDIR)/ufa.make
```

But I couldnot see this variable referenced again. What is use of defining this variable again? Does it have any special significance or usage?

Comment: It has no special meaning to make.  It's also not something I'm aware of as a commonly used variable.  So it must be an idiom used by this makefile system.

Comment: Thanks, since Im new to make, I was thinking perhaps its a special variable that has some special usage. But after your comment, it looks useless to me, why define it and use it nowhere.

Comment: @user496934. You can create new file during build and emit info that file was generated by `THISMAKEFILE` and will be overriden during next build, so people won't need to guess what changed given file. For example file can contain build time or commit ID

Comment: We can't say, you're the one who can see the makefiles not us! :).  Maybe the variable is used somewhere that you didn't find.  Or, it's vestigial.